# HTML elements made with function have same event listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
const add_compressor = (number) => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'compressor';

    let threshold = document.createElement('input');
        threshold.type = 'number';
        threshold.className = 'input_number';
        threshold.addEventListener('input', () => {
            compressors[number].threshold.value = threshold.value;
        })

    div.appendChild(threshold);
    added_effects.appendChild(div);
}

add_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (select_effect.value != 'Add Effect...') {
        if (select_effect.value === 'compressor') {
            compressors[compressors.length] = effects[select_effect.value];
            add_compressor(compressors.length - 1);
        }
    }
})
```

I am trying to allow the creation of more than 1 compressor for the Web Audio API with this `add_compressor` function. Everything works except the `threshold.addEventListener` is linked to every compressor that is created. I am wondering if it is possible to create the event listeners for multiple compressors this way. Here is a JS fiddle showing the problem in the console.

https://jsfiddle.net/0L1my6kp/

Changing any of the input boxes for the compressors will change the threshold.value for all compressors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only create a compressor object once, and reference the same object every time.

So instead of this

```
const effects = {
    compressor: context.createDynamicsCompressor()
}
```

it should be

```
const effects = {
    compressor: context.createDynamicsCompressor
}
```

then you create a new compressor when you click the button. Check out the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0L1my6kp/4/